# buggy permutation in python

Tags: python, recursion, permutation

I have written java code for permutation but I failed to translate to python. They are both pass by values but I cannot figure out why. The output give me `[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3enter code here]]`

```
def permutation(nums):
    nums.sort()
    ans = []
    backTrack([], ans, nums)
    return ans

def backTrack(tempList, ans, nums):
    if len(tempList) == len(nums):
        newList = tempList[:]
        ans.append(newList)
    else:
        for i in range(len(nums)):
            if nums[i] in tempList:
                continue
            tempList.append(nums[i])
            backTrack(tempList, ans, nums)
            tempList = tempList[:-1]

ans = permutation([1, 2, 3])
print(ans)
```

Comment: Quick reminder that [python has a library for permutations!](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF you are trying to do if for a class then I found a great one that explains it.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/generate-all-the-permutation-of-a-list-in-python/

I modified a couple of things.

```
import sys
# Python function to print permutations of a given list 
def permutation(data): 

    # If data is empty then there are no permutations 
    if len(data) == 0: 
        return [] 

    # If there is only one element in data then, only 
    # one permuatation is possible 
    if len(data) == 1: 
        return [data] 

    # Find the permutations for lst if there are 
    # more than 1 characters 

    l = [] # empty list that will store current permutation 

    # Iterate the input(data) and calculate the permutation 
    for i in range(len(data)): 
       m = data[i] 

       # Extract data[i] or m from the list.  remLst is 
       # remaining list 
       remLst = data[:i] + data[i+1:] 

       # Generating all permutations where m is first 
       # element 
       for p in permutation(remLst): 
           l.append([m] + p) 
    return l 


# Driver program to test above function 
#data = list('123') 
for p in permutation(list(sys.argv[1])): 
    print(p)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change:

```
tempList = tempList[:-1]
```

To:

```
tempList.pop()
```

---

The reason is that `tempList = tempList[:-1]` **creates a new list in the current scope (current function call)**. Hence, **the parent function which called this function will still be pointing to the old list** i.e. parent function will have a different value of `tempList` than you expect.